# Lagging sculpting with over 1 milion polygons on a High-End PC

Tags: sculpting

As in the title I have the problem with non responsive scultping while I’m working on my T-Rex.
The brush is so delayed that I can’t sculpt, sometimes I have to wait like 5 seconds to see the effect, I tried to serach on the web how to resolve the problem but I couldn’t find anything, I will add that I’m not using any modifier and my PC specs are quite good:

1. CPU Ryzen 3900 12 cores
2. GPU RTX 2080 Super
3. RAM 32 Gb 3600 Mhz

(I have the lattest drivers)

Please help me I’m quite newbie, I was searching how to resolve it since yesterday and still nothing :(

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the .blend so that I can try to reproduce on my end?

Comment: @Cultmethod sure, here you go! :) Thanks BTW! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gt0Vnes3OWtwQM4KheMtd07xs4TYY49/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Higher cores don't help if there are operations, that can only run on a single core. There may not be a solution to your problem other than higher single core speed (and hyperthreading etc., but lets leave that out)

Comment: @WhatAMesh I doubt that my single core is such bad to dont rect 1,5 milion poligons, when I see other people sculpting on higher values 50 times higher (like 50 milions), that would mean that their clock speed is 250 Ghz?

Comment: There are different operations, brush sizes and settings, such as dyntopo that increase or decrease the needed amount of computation. If you have Photoshop for example, open a file, make some art and then drag the smudge tool with large scale accross the image. Won't be smooth, even though it should be a very simple operation. But if you are that defensive to a simple comment maybe you shouldn't ask in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened your file, and sculpting was definitely a little bit laggy, but nowhere near what you're describing (Having to wait 5 seconds before seeing the result of a sculpting change). However I managed to fix the problem by doing the following:

1. Hide the "Teeth", "Bones", and "Eyes" collections.
2. Important: Deactivate the Armature modifier from displaying in the viewport.

[image: Sculpt]

After I did this performance increased drastically for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are a genius man! I love you! :D The problem is solved although it is normal that when I'm trying to use dyntopo with small resolution there are still lags? But without dyntopo works very well.

Comment: Definitely not a genius, took me awhile to figure out what the hell was going on :) Glad I could help!